# How to dynamically display most visited links in a SharePoint Site to site visitors?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, css, asp.net, tags

I'm trying to display most visited links in an internet-facing SharePoint site to site visitors in a dynamic way.

For example:
The most visited links will be colored based on the clicks on those links:

- Page1 link will be colored in red as it's a hot link (most visited)
- Page2 link will be colored in blue (less number of visits)..and so on.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you can use a Web Analytics web part to display most visited pages in Site on the page.

[How to display most visited sites in SharePoint 2010 using Web Analytics web part](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/find-most-visited-site-and-pages-in-site-collection-using-sh/)

If you are using SharePoint 2013, you can use a Content Search web part to display most visited pages on the page.

[How to display most visited sites in SharePoint 2013 using Content Search web part](http://sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-Most-Visited-Sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-SharePoint-2013-Web-Analytics)

The results in these web parts are dynamic. After that, you can use code (such as JavaScript, css) to change the color for the first, second, third … result.

Comment: is there any crawled / managed property for sharepoint search, that could show which were the last files / sites current user has visited? thanks